# The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' while using simple code

Tags: flutter

i have little and basic code but dont understand why it is saying:

"The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'."

I searched here on stackoverflow but all of these arent working for this kind of problem.

Hope you can helpe me!!!

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {


  Future addInvoice()async {
    var invoice = {
      "name":"testname",
      "mobile":"testmobile",
      "email":"testemail",
      "invId":"testinvId",
      "amount":"testamount",
      "discout":"testdiscount",
      "productname":"testproductname",
    };
    var invoiceresponse = await http.post('https://XYZ/test.php',body: invoice);
    if (invoiceresponse.statusCode == 200) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>myPdfViewer(invoiceId: "testinvId",),),);
      print(invoiceresponse.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: new Text(
              "Save",
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              addInvoice();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `BuildContext` to your function like

```dart
    Future addInvoice(BuildContext context)async ...
```

And dont forget to pass it as argument when invoking in build function.

Comment: Can you please send me an email or twitter message?

Comment: @fynn1307 I updated my profile with my email, feel free to contact me with it

Comment: i send you an email egain, please help once again...